# Java threads in order

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm learning threads so I wanted to make a program which has two types of threads: one that writes random numbers and the other one which checks if the current number matches some specific number. The threads call write() and read(int) methods from the Numbers class. To make things more clear, I want my main program to look like this:

```
Numbers n = new Numbers();
new WritingThread(n);
new ReadingThread(n,3);
new ReadingThread(n,5);
```

So the output would be something like this:

```
2 
7
3 !!! MATCH !!!
8
5 !!! MATCH !!!
1
...
```

The thing is that threads are not executed in order. I want to first execute the WritingThread, and then all the ReadingThreads. Because this way a new random number would be written and only one thread would have the chance to check if the numbers match. Here is the code:

**class Numbers**:

```
public class Numbers {
int number;
boolean written = false;

public synchronized void write() {
    while (written)
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    number = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    System.out.print("\n" + number);
    written = true;
    notifyAll();
}

public synchronized void check(int n) {
    while (!written)
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    System.out.print(" Reading thread: "    + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    if (n == number) 
        System.out.print(" !!! MATCH !!! ");
    notify();
    written = false;
}
}
```

**class WritingThread**:

```
public class WritingThread extends Thread {
    Numbers n;
    WritingThread(Numbers n){
        this.n = n;
        start();
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            n.write();
        }
    }
}
```

**class ReadingThread**:

```
public class ReadingThread extends Thread{
Numbers n;
int number;
public ReadingThread(Numbers n, int number){
    this.n = n;
    this.number = number;
    start();
}

public void run(){
    while(true){
        n.check(number);
    }
}
}
```

And the output:

```
3 Reading thread: Thread-2
3 Reading thread: Thread-1 !!! MATCH !!! 
0 Reading thread: Thread-2
5 Reading thread: Thread-1
0 Reading thread: Thread-2
0 Reading thread: Thread-1
5 Reading thread: Thread-2 !!! MATCH !!! 
8 Reading thread: Thread-1
```

I know i could make one thread which has an array of numbers to check, but I am curious how could it be done this way. Thanks.

Comment: What are you asking? Try just printing the matches, or read up on [java.util.concurrent.Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Comment: I thought so, but how to implement it, where?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch notice the 4th row in the output. it should be match but it isn't, because Thread-1 was checking for match and Thread-2 didn't get the chance

Comment: Yes, because Thread-1 was looking for a 3 (not a 5). And was scheduled first (or at least "printed" first). Concurrency is hard.

Comment: You have two reading threads and only one writing thread. You also have a single `boolean` lock. How do you expect this to work exactly? Hello race hazard.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes, I know, I'm asking is there a way for both threads to check the number, not just one at a time.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I don't know, that's why I'm asking

Comment: @ElliottFrisch no. Look: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41011334/threads.png)
There is no match for number 3

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am sorry, I really don't understand how all that works, I'm very new to Java. I now added a static field which counts matches and writes match count to output. Still the same thing, look: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41011334/threads2.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start with your example. You have two consumers and one boolean flag. Think through the logic. Let's call our three threads `W`, `C1` and `C2`.

- `W` post 5
- `W` set flag to `true`
- `W` send `notifyAll`
- `C2` awake
- `C1` awake
- `C2` acquire lock
- `C1` block
- `C2` no match
- `C2` notify
- `W` awake
- `W blocks`
- `C2` release lock
- `C1` acquire lock
- flag is false, `C1` waits (releases monitor)
- flag is false, `C2` waits (releases monitor)
- `GOTO` start

This is just *one* if the many possible ways in which this code can fun. Any time the lock needs to be acquired there is a free for all and of the threads waiting for it only one can get the lock. That thread will check the value set and reset the flag. If that thread is not the one that the value was intended for it is still consumed.

It should be fairly obvious that you have a race hazard. You are using a single queue for two consumer threads. Each consumer thread is fighting for the queue. Your queue is thread safe in that no more than one thread can read the single item from it at any one time but it causes a race hazard as each consumer thread expects to be the only one reading it. If the wrong thread reads the item then the other thread cannot see it.

The only way to resolve this is to have one queue per thread. The producer puts the same item into each consumer thread's private queue and each consumer thread takes items from its queue and reads them.

Here is an example using an `ExecutorSerivce`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final class Consumer implements Runnable {

        private final BlockingQueue<Integer> q = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
        private final int search;

        public Consumer(final int search) {
            this.search = search;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    if (q.take() == search) {
                        System.out.println("Found magic number.");
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        public Queue<Integer> getQ() {
            return q;
        }
    }

    final class Producer implements Runnable {

        final Random r = new Random();
        final Iterable<Queue<Integer>> qs;

        public Producer(final Iterable<Queue<Integer>> qs) {
            this.qs = qs;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                final int i = r.nextInt();
                for (final Queue<Integer> q : qs) {
                    q.offer(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    final int numConsumers = 5;
    final Collection<Queue<Integer>> qs = new LinkedList<>();
    final ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    for (int i = 0; i < numConsumers; ++i) {
        final Consumer c = new Consumer(i);
        qs.add(c.getQ());
        es.submit(c);
    }
    es.submit(new Producer(qs));
}
```

You are likely to get very few hits with this example as `Random.nextInt()` is used. If you want to get more hits reduce the range of the generated random numbers by calling `Random.nextInt(int max)` which generates numbers `[0, max)`.

As you can see each `Consumer` has a queue of items to check and it blocks using the `BlockingQueue` API to wait for new items. The `Producer` puts the same item into each of the `Consumer`'s queues in turn.